# Seeking best List to use as BookMarker

Tags: 2013, custom-list

I want to save important URLS within SharePoint 2013. In doing so, I hope to stop cluttering up my browser's bookmarks. Can anyone suggest the best type of List to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best out-of-the-box approach would be **Links** list. By default, it has 2 columns (URL + Notes), but you can also add additional, custom metadata.

You will be able to surface information from that list through a web part called "Links Web Part" on any page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: By MetaData do you mean the additional column information I add?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to customize that list the same way as a custom list - add new columns, create views, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Select a Custom List template and create two fields with type as **single line text** and other as **hyperlink or Picture**. Store your values in there.